# Split report into Quarters of a Fiscal Year

Tags: date, crystal-reports, fiscal

I wish to break up the number of screenings into different quarters of a fiscal year from July 1 to June 30.

[image: by Quarters]

I tried the following but it kept giving me 0.

```
if {enrollment.date} in {?startdate} to DateAdd("m", 4, {?startdate})
then (DistinctCount ({enrollment.id}))
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this a cross tab report or normal report

Comment: I should say crosstab should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 4 formula fields for quarter clinic 
create 4 formula  fields for quarter state

```
-- per quarter formula
if Month (date({Command.mydate})) in 1 to 3 then    --qt1
    <number>
else 0
```

Comment: What is the <number> part of the equation?

Comment: Your number field or data